# How can I add a pattern attribute to a phone field?

Tags: forms, 9

I am trying add `pattern` `attribute` to phone field of `drupal`'s core feedback form. I am trying to do like this in `mytheme.theme`

```
function mytheme_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if('contact_message_feedback_form' == $form_id){
    $form['field_phone']['#attributes'][] = ['pattern' => '\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})'];
   }
}
```

but `pattern` attribute not showing up (also cleared caches).
I am using `9.1.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not an array, try to use a Attribute object :

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;
if (empty($form['field_phone']['#attributes']) {
    $form['field_phone']['#attributes'] = new Attribute();
}

if (is_a($form['field_phone']['#attributes'], Attribute::class)) {
    $form['field_phone']['#attributes']->setAttribute('pattern', '\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})');
} 
else {
    $form['field_phone']['#attributes'][] = ['pattern' => '\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})'];
}
```

Edit:

I checked on a D8 instance I got on my IDE and I managed to have it working with the following code :

```
$form['elements']['phone']['#attributes']['pattern'] = '#^+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})$#';
```

You may need to replace 'phone' by the field name you set in the IDE.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. You can check once try adding `phone` field in website feedback form.